# htaccess subdomain map with wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, wildcard

I've been through this and googled to high heaven but just can't get it working so apologies in advance.

I'm trying to redirect a subdomain to a folder whilst not changing the URL in the address bar, so for example

sub.domain-name.co.uk should execute the code in domain-name.co.uk/codebase

further, the www should be ignored. I have a wildcard record setup so there's no DNS issues.

I've tested with test.domain-name.co.uk and it just gives an error 500

My current htaccess is as follows

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain-name\.co.uk$
    RewriteCond %1 !=www
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codebase/$1 [L, NC]
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Still searching ... any help please?